# `gem install` on ubuntu gives invalid byte sequence error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, debian, rvm

I used RVM to install Ruby on Ubuntu (Debian).  I can use irb and run ruby scripts.

However, when I try to install **any** gem I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

This also happens when I use any value for the gem, e.g., `gem install garbage`.

This happens with both Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.

Here is what the command `locale` reports:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_SG:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Here is the trace:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:862:in `sub!'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:862:in `block (2 levels) in parse_resolv_conf'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:861:in `each'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:861:in `block in parse_resolv_conf'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:860:in `open'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:860:in `parse_resolv_conf'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:892:in `default_config_hash'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:913:in `block in lazy_initialize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:906:in `lazy_initialize'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:342:in `block in lazy_initialize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:340:in `lazy_initialize'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:494:in `each_resource'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:475:in `getresource'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:88:in `api_endpoint'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source.rb:42:in `api_uri'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source.rb:170:in `load_specs'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:266:in `tuples_for'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:226:in `block in available_specs'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:222:in `available_specs'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:102:in `search_for_dependency'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:216:in `find_gems_with_sources'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:292:in `find_spec_by_name_and_version'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:166:in `available_set_for'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:418:in `resolve_dependencies'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:371:in `install'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `install_gem'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:263:in `block in install_gems'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:259:in `each'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:259:in `install_gems'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:171:in `execute'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable backtrace in **~/.gemrc**:

```
---
backtrace: true
```

do install, and provide trace log.

According the trace log, it seems that something was invalid in ruby installation. It need to be debugged yourself. Just open the file. `/home/crazybob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb` on 862 line, and before it insert lines: `puts str.encoding`, and `puts str.inspect`, or something similar to it, to see the `String` in which the error is thrown.

Also try to reinstall [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), or install latest version with [rmv](/questions/tagged/rmv).

Comment: I'ved added the trace log

Comment: I think I see the issue.  The resolv.conf has some weird data.  Let me look into that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

my **/etc/resolv.conf** had some binary garbage, which caused this problem. Not sure, why **resolv.conf** had this data.

Comment: system **resolv.conf** is fixed by system scripts, fix by hands **resolv.conf** for the specific interface instead.